# How can i save and fetch array values in local storage

Tags: angular, typescript

I am able to save an array as shown below:

```
list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

but I wish to save a bit more complicated case like:

```
[{name:"saurabh" , age: 5 , sex:"male"}];
```

Now how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **`JSON.stringify`** and call **`setItem`**

```
let myArray =  [{name:"saurabh" , age: 5 , sex:"male"}];
localStorage.setItem('userCache', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

Comment: and then JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userCache'));

Comment: thanks, i am also able to push data aswell, now i want to retrieve each array object on page line by line and click to delete..can you please guide so that i can achieve my crud , this is what i am getting in localstorage at the moment - key - `education` , value - `[{"title":"saurabh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},[{"title":"aman","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"}]]`

Comment: what do you mean delete line by line?

Comment: click on a object to delete it, if i click on `saurabh` then its relevant data should be removed to storage

Comment: you can use find() with array and then get the item and call slice